# Golang insist that package-scoped function has a particular type

Tags: go

If I have a type synonym `FooType` and a function `Foo` is there a way to insist that `Foo` is an instance of `FooType`. I'd like an explicit `FooType` so I can use it in a type switch.

I don't want to use a `var` and function literal if I can avoid it because then I don't get an error when I attempt to redefine a function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type FooType func(a int, b float64) float32

// foo happens to be of FooType, but this relationship isn't
// enforced by the compiler.
func Foo(a int, b float64) float32 {
    return 2.4
}

func main () {
    fmt.Printf("type of foo: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(foo))
}
```

The motivation for this is I have two types of filters that can process streams of text or structured objects.

```
// process items from channel
function filter1(in <-chan interface{}, out chan<- chan interface{}) {
    for item := range in {
        out <- doStuff(item)
    }
}

// process items from Scanner
function filter2(scanner *Scanner, out chan<- chan interface{}) {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        out <- doStuff(scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to write a function that takes an `*exec.Cmd` and an array of filters and combines them.

Comment: Can you give an example of the type switch you plan on using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `Foo` to an anonymous variable of type `FooType` which will the compiler will complain about if the type doesn't match, e.g.:

```
package main

type FooType func(a int, b float64) float32

func Foo(a int, b float64) float32 {
    return 2.4
}

func NotAFoo(a string, b bool) float32 {
    return 2.4
}

var _ FooType = Foo
var _ FooType = NotAFoo

func main() {
}
```

Note that the `var _ FooType = NotAFoo` blows up.  If you comment it out, the program runs fine. [Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/OmToFwJ2p5)